# Is there really no proper way to get a hold of Node class of LinkedList?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Use case: I want to keep a maxHeap of elements within the list to be able to have quick access to max value. Also want to be able to keep the order of the last element that were inserted. Essentially want to build MaxStack.

I am looking over the API of LinkedList and there doesn't seem to be any APIs exposing the Node of the list, for me to be able to hold the actual node and then ask the list to delete the node instead of having to iterate over the list each time I want to delete the element.

With MaxHeap and exact node the deletion would be O(log n) due to MaxHeap while with iteration over the list the deletion would be O(n).

So as far as for question one: whether we can get a hold of the node: looks like I already know the answer to since Node class is private...

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

So it looks like standard implementation doesn't actually allows us to take advantage of LinkedList properties, which is quite surprising (unless I am hopefully missing something here, I guess one way is using reflection to get a hold of the Node but that doesn't sound tidy at all).

Now onto the follow-up question: is there sub-standard library to use then for LinkedList implementation that actually allows us to get a hold of the `Node` to be able to do deletions from the list in O(1) (if we know the node reference).

Comment: You are correct that java.util.LinkedList does not support your use case. If it were me, I would first check that I really need O(logn) removals, and just use an ArrayList if not. If you do really need it, you can implement it using a `PriorityQueue<Node<E>>` where you define your own Node class to make a linked list.

Comment: "So as far as for question one: whether we can get a hold of the node: looks like I already know the answer to since Node class is private." - FYI... The fact that `Node` is `private` doesn't have anything to do with whether or not you have access to instances of that class.  The `private`-ness would prevent you from doing things like easily creating an instance yourself, but the JVM does allow a non-private method to return an instance of a private class that might only visible inside the class that defines that method, for example.

Comment: The nodes in java.util.LinkedList are part of the private implementation details of an encapsulated class. The class provides a public API that promises the performance you would expect of a LinkedList. If you want a class that gives you features of both a linkedlist and a heap with O(log n) deletion, you might have to build it yourself.

Comment: @AndyThomas I would expect to be able to delete an element from the middle of LinkedList in O(1) while with current implementation its O(n).

Comment: @user7858768 - A linked list lets you remove a node in the middle of a linked list in O(1). However, *finding* that node can be O(n) -- unless you've got a data structure that's more than a linked list.